# ¿Como puedo implementar tres recaptcha en una pagina index.php?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-blade, captcha

Estoy teniendo problemas al momento de cargar tres recaptcha en un mismo archivo index.blade.php en donde existe tres formularios  diferentes, estos a su vez requieren validación con recaptcha, pero pasa que cuando carga el primero uno los dos siguientes dejan de funcionar.

- Esto es posible de implementar?

De ser afirmativo la implementacion, cuales son sus recomendaciones de acuerdo a su experiencia para realizar esta operación.

Comment: Esto es muy amplio, de todas formas sí que se puede pero no te sabría decir como

Comment: por favor agrega el código respectivo

Comment: Hola Jose te sugiero revisar [ask] para reformules que tu pregunta para que de esta forma sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas ya que fue marcada como demasiada amplia. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio.

Comment: Yo quitaría el captcha de los formularios y lo pondría en un popup para llamarlo desde los formularios al hacer submit. Es decir, la idea de un captcha es que en una sola acción, determinar si el usuario es persona o no, poner 3 complica la página y no tiene sentido.